# jQuery append span into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have a menu structure. With the following:

```
<ul id="quicktabs-ileti_im">
<li><a href="#qt-ileti_im-ui-tabs1" tabindex="0" class="">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#qt-ileti_im-ui-tabs1" tabindex="0" class="">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#qt-ileti_im-ui-tabs1" tabindex="0" class="">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

And want to:

```
<li><a href="#qt-ileti_im-ui-tabs1" tabindex="0" class=""><span>1</span></a></li>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$("#quicktabs-ileti_im ul li a").append('<span>');
```

But result:

```
<li><a href="#qt-ileti_im-ui-tabs1" tabindex="0" class="">1<span></span></a></li>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: where is your jquery code..??

Comment: Sorry, updated my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

`$("#quicktabs-ileti_im li a").wrapInner('<span>');`

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) for documentation.

Comment: Extra `ul` in the selector

Comment: I fixed your answer so it would actually work. I removed the ul

Comment: To be fair, the selector could be reduced to `$('#quicktabs-ileti_im a')` without issue, looking at the example.

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna: If it works, way of thanking is accepting and votin

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) or [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$("#quicktabs-ileti_im li a").contents().wrap("<span></span>");
```

or

```
$("#quicktabs-ileti_im li a").wrapInner("<span/>")
```

**Examples:**

- [wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/5G4qh/)
- [wrapInner](http://jsfiddle.net/5G4qh/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Voted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by [**wrapInner()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) like this:
[**jsFiddle Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/VZf5f/2/)

```
$('#quicktabs-ileti_im li a').wrapInner("<span></span>");
```

Comment: result: <span><a>1</a></span>

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna Thanks. +1 for your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#quicktabs-ileti_im > li > a").contents().wrap("<span />");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is not correct.

`ul` has `id= quicktabs-ileti_im`. that means that the element can be referred with either of 2 ways.

```
$('#quicktabs-ileti_im')

$('ul#quicktabs-ileti_im')
```

that means your selector should be...

`$('#quicktabs-ileti_im li a')` or simply `$('#quicktabs-ileti_im a')`.

As for the answer you can use either [.wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) or [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) JQuery functions.

```
$("#quicktabs-ileti_im a").wrapInner('<span />');

$("#quicktabs-ileti_im a").contents().wrap('<span />');
```

Comment: Thank you! Voted this answer.